# How many subsets of size $n+1$ can we have so no two of them have intersection of size $n$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a set of size $m$. How many sets of fixed size $n+1$ can we have so that no two of them have an intersection of size $n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A different perspective**: Consider a regular graph of $\binom{m}{n+1}$ vertices and degree $(n+1)(m-n-1)$. We identify an vertex with a $n+1$ element subset of $[m]$ and a pair of vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$have an edge between them if $|v_1\cap v_2|=n$. We are looking for the length of maximum independent set in this graph.

Answer (score 1):

Build all subsets, where each contains $n$ out of $m-k$ elements: $\binom{m-k}{n}$.

The maximum number of elements shared by any pair of subsets is $n-1$.

Take the remaining $k$ elements, and add one (unique) element to each subset.

The maximum number of elements shared by any pair of subsets is still $n-1$.

---

Now, in order for this method to yield the maximum number of subsets:

- Find the value of $k$ for which $\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]$ is maximal
- As you can see, possible values of $k$ are in the range $[1,m-n]$
- Hence, the maximum number of subsets is $\max[\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]]$ for $k\in[1,m-n]$

---

**A few examples:**

- If $m-n=1$:

  - $k=1\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[1,\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(m-1-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+0)!}{n!0!}]=\min[1,1]=1$
- If $m-n=2$:

  - $k=1\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[1,\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(m-1-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+1)!}{n!1!}]=\min[1,n+1]=1$
  - $k=2\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[2,\frac{(m-2)!}{n!(m-2-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+0)!}{n!0!}]=\min[1,1]=1$
- If $m-n=3$:

  - $k=1\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[1,\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(m-1-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+2)!}{n!2!}]=\min[1,\frac{\dots}{2!}]=1$
  - $k=2\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[2,\frac{(m-2)!}{n!(m-2-n)!}]=\min[2,\frac{(n+1)!}{n!1!}]=\min[2,n+1]=2$
  - $k=3\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[3,\frac{(m-3)!}{n!(m-3-n)!}]=\min[3,\frac{(n+0)!}{n!0!}]=\min[3,1]=1$
- If $m-n=4$:

  - $k=1\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[1,\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(m-1-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+3)!}{n!3!}]=\min[1,\frac{\dots}{3!}]=1$
  - $k=2\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[2,\frac{(m-2)!}{n!(m-2-n)!}]=\min[2,\frac{(n+2)!}{n!2!}]=\min[2,\frac{\dots}{2!}]=2$
  - $k=3\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[3,\frac{(m-3)!}{n!(m-3-n)!}]=\min[3,\frac{(n+1)!}{n!1!}]=\min[3,n+1]=2$ to $3$
  - $k=4\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[4,\frac{(m-4)!}{n!(m-4-n)!}]=\min[4,\frac{(n+0)!}{n!0!}]=\min[4,1]=1$
- If $m-n=5$:

  - $k=1\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[1,\frac{(m-1)!}{n!(m-1-n)!}]=\min[1,\frac{(n+4)!}{n!4!}]=\min[1,\frac{\dots}{4!}]=1$
  - $k=2\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[2,\frac{(m-2)!}{n!(m-2-n)!}]=\min[2,\frac{(n+3)!}{n!3!}]=\min[2,\frac{\dots}{3!}]=2$
  - $k=3\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[3,\frac{(m-3)!}{n!(m-3-n)!}]=\min[3,\frac{(n+2)!}{n!2!}]=\min[3,\frac{\dots}{2!}]=3$
  - $k=4\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[4,\frac{(m-4)!}{n!(m-4-n)!}]=\min[4,\frac{(n+1)!}{n!1!}]=\min[4,n+1]=2$ to $4$
  - $k=5\implies\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]=\min[5,\frac{(m-5)!}{n!(m-5-n)!}]=\min[5,\frac{(n+0)!}{n!0!}]=\min[5,1]=1$

Comment: So what is the answer to the question?

Comment: @user4140: Please see updated answer above. In short, the maximum number of subsets is $\max[\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]]$ for $k\in[1,m-n]$, which means that you need to iterate all values of $k\in[1,m-n]$, and find the one for which $\min[k,\binom{m-k}{n}]$ is maximal.

Comment: @barak manos: The above answer is the 'maximum' produced by the method you proposed or is it the actual 'maximum'? If I am not mistaken, it is the former.

Comment: @talegari: Using the correct $k$, this method builds up the maximum possible number of subsets according to the definition. So the "actual maximum" as you call it, is equal to the number of subsets that this method returns (using the correct $k$ of course).